# Questions regarding the derivation procedure of the Karman-Howarth-Monin relation

Tags: fluid-dynamics, velocity, flow, navier-stokes, turbulence

I was reading the book "Turbulence" written by Uriel Frisch (1995) and got stuck in following the proof of the Karman-Howarth-Monin relation. Although there is already a [thread](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/10549/) about it, I have different questions.

[image]

[image]

The proof is given above. My questions are:

1. How the two identities $\partial \langle(\cdot)\rangle=-\partial_i' \langle(\cdot)\rangle=-\nabla_l \langle(\cdot)\rangle$ are derived from the homogeneity?
2. Why does incompressibility mean $\langle v_i' \partial_i p\rangle=\langle v_i \partial_i' p'\rangle=0$?